# Production Android app showing Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

How can a production app show a class not found error to users but on the emulator it works just fine with Android 9.0.  Shouldnt the emulator also break or show an error during compiling or building?

**java.lang.RuntimeException:**

> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:354)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:245)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)   at java.lang.Thread.run
>   (Thread.java:764)

**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

> at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.
>   (AbstractHttpClient.java:182)   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.
>   (DefaultHttpClient.java:150)   at
>   com.exposure.utilities.RestClient.executeRequest (RestClient.java:162)
>   at com.exposure.utilities.RestClient.Execute (RestClient.java:127)
>   at com.exposure.utilities.Utility.getData (Utility.java:162)   at
>   com.exposure.utilities.DataTask.doInBackground (DataTask.java:26)   at
>   com.exposure.utilities.DataTask.doInBackground (DataTask.java:9)   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:333)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:**

> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
>   (ClassLoader.java:379)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
>   (ClassLoader.java:312)

Comment: Is this happening on device with android pie?

Comment: Yes, but I have 450 apps, why in the world would it be throwing an error on load where no one can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is due to http client being deprecated. Add below code to your manifest application tag.

`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

With android pie they have deprecated support for Apache HTTP client starting from andorid pie, check change log for reference https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Comment: This is Android 9 and mainly on Pixel 1, 2 and 3.  Why in the world would I be able to submit an app to the store that would crash on load?  Emulator worked just fine.

Comment: Android 9 works fine, without that update in the emulator, no crash.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the http connection code to the non deprecated one.